# Provide a GET method in JSON and XML

Tags: java, xml, json, rest, get

I'm developing REST services using Jersey.

So, if I have an object of User type (which contains information about a User), like:

```
User userObj = new User();
```

And I want to provide that information by a GET method, in both **JSON** and **XML**.

I already can provide it in JSON, by using `gson.toJson(userObj)`. And what about XML?

Thanks

Comment: Checkout:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the JAXB API. It provides a way to map XML to classes with simple getter/setter methods. http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_1_1-Introduction.html#About%20JAXB

Comment: So, can I do something like:

   `@GET `
   `@Path("/userinfo/{id}")
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public String getUserInfo(@PathParam("id") String id) {

String users = null;
User user = null;

user = new UserManager().getUserInfo(id);
                
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(User.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
 
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(user, System.out);  
users = jaxbMarshaller.toString();

        return users;
} `

Comment: +1 - Also since JAXB is the default binding layer for JAX-RS you can just return a JAXB model class and the JAX-RS implementation will leverage JAXB to convert it to XML:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html